# selector in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I am having some problems with the sub nav on this site I am building. I dont think I am selecting items properly in my jquery. Im sure its just a little thing that needs to be done, but I dont know how to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDErp/

I am trying to make it so when you click on one of the subnav links a different div will open up revealing a color. For some reason when I click on a link it only reveals the first(red) div.

If you can help that would be great!

Comment: Could you please post the relevant HTML and JavaScript here? We want to make sure the question is still valuable if JSFiddle goes down.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with this line:

```
var $menuelement = $('.thumb').eq($(this).parent().index());
```

`a.subnav`'s direct parent is an `h4`. Using `index()` on this element would mean you want the index of that `h4` in relation to its siblings (there are none). You actually want the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest) `li` ancestor.

Use:

```
var $menuelement = $('.thumb').eq($(this).closest("li").index());
```

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/286LV/

Answer (score 0):

I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDErp/1/

What I did was us the `href` attribute as the selector for the div to show.